# Keeping a GUI open while iterating through images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to create a gui that will iterate through images but I'm having trouble keeping the GUI open. It closes after the first image.

```
display = figure('Name', 'Images');
continue_button = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Continue',...
        'Callback', %what should I put here%); 

blue_button = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Blue', 'Position', [400 35 75 20], 'Callback', @show_blue); 

function [] = show_blue(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    imshow(original(:,:,3));
end

for i = 1:length(images)
    imshow(imread(images(i).name));
```

My code looks like that. I looked at the matlab documentation examples and after `callback` they had `set()` but that method doesn't apply to me since I'm changing any component of the gui. Hence, I'm not sure what condition to apply.

I want the gui to display the next image only when I click next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Together with your callback handler you should also declare a variable for storing the current image offset being shown. Instead of inserting it into a variable, you can use the UserData property of the button.

```
display = figure('Name','Images');
continue_button = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Continue','Callback',@ContinueHandler,'UserData',[1 length(images)]);

% When the figure is created, show the first image by default...
imshow(imread(images(1).name));
```

Now, when the button is clicked:

```
function ContinueHandler(obj,evd)
    % retrieve the images data
    img_data = obj.UserData;
    img_off = img_data(1) + 1;
    img_len = img_data(2);

    % Retrieve the next image or restart if the last image is being shown...
    if (img_off > img_len)
        img_nex = 1;
    else
        img_nex = img_off;
    end

    % Clear the axes and show the next image...
    cla();
    imshow(imread(images(img_nex).name));

    % Update the images data...
    obj.UserData = [img_nex img_len];
end
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you! Can you please the logic behind what is happening in terms of the arguments passed into the uicontrol and the parameters of the function? I don't quite understand the logic behind it. Also, if i just want to close the gui once I reach last image, what would I do? I tried `close(display)` but that didn't really work.

Comment: Wait sorry, not everything works right. So, I have other buttons that do other things and those no longer work. Why is that?

Comment: Actually, the arguments being passed to the callback are always two in this case: the object on which the callback was fired (the button) and a structure representing the events data (useless here). Using a breakpoint you should see what's going on easily.

Comment: I've added a simple example of an extra button.

Comment: I'm no longer able to click on the "blue" button. It says error while evaluating uicontrol

Comment: Does it enters the show_blue event handler? Or the error is thrown before?

Comment: It's being thrown before.

Comment: It seems that it's not related to this answer. Maybe you are missing something in your code? Closing and opening ends on functions? I can't figure out.

Comment: I see, thank you anyway! I get the main bit working!

Comment: Also, is there a proper way to close the gui if the last image is reached?

Comment: You can try with a close on the display variable... it should work, it should be enough. But actually, closing the figure inside that handler, which is fired by a button contained in it, may lead to unpredictable problems. I suggest you to create a small timer with a minimum delay that closes it instead of directly closing it into the button callback.